# "GET PROCESSING OPTIONS" always 6700(wrong Lc or Le)

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, emv

I'm trying to read a smartcard via my LG P710 Optimus L7 2.
I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.nfc.cc/2012/04/02/android-app-reads-paypass-and-paywave-creditcards/)

I can select the "1PAY.SYS.DDF01" directory
I can select the Application

But I can't perform an "GET PROCESSING OPTIONS"
It always result in an 6700 error (Lc or Le wrong)

here is my code

```
NfcAdapter mNFCAdapter;
Intent intent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TextView mTextView;
String[][] techList;
IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    mNFCAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);


    techList = new String[][]{
            new String[]
                    { MifareClassic.class.getName() },
            new String[]
                    { IsoDep.class.getName() }
            };

    filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    // add type of tag data you want to have - here ndef -> plain text
    try {
        filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    filters[1] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[1].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    filters[1].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    filters[2] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[2].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    filters[2].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();
    mTextView.setText(action);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    IsoDep tagIsoDep;

    if((tagIsoDep = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent)) != null)
        if(handleIsoDep(tagIsoDep))
            return;

}
     private boolean handleIsoDep(IsoDep tag){
    try{ 
        tag.connect(); 
        tag.setTimeout(20); 
        byte[] responseAPDU;


        //2PAY.SYS.DDF01
        byte[] select_Dir = new byte[]{ 
                (byte)0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0e,
                (byte)0x32, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x2e,
                (byte)0x53, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x44, 
                (byte)0x44, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31
        };

        //Select CC Applet
        byte[] select_Applet = new byte[]{ 
                (byte)0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)7, 
                (byte)0xa0, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x04,
                (byte)0x30, (byte)0x60
        };

        //Send GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command
        byte[] Send_Get = new byte[]{ 
                (byte)0x80,(byte)0xA8,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,
                (byte)0x83,(byte)0x00,
                (byte)0x00
        };


        responseAPDU = tag.transceive(select_Dir); 
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + handleResponse(responseAPDU));
```

this returns the APDU-Statusword 9000 -> success

```
        responseAPDU = tag.transceive(select_Applet); 
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + handleResponse(responseAPDU));
```

this returns the APDU-Statusword 9000 -> success

```
        responseAPDU = tag.transceive(Send_Get); 
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + handleResponse(responseAPDU));
```

and this one is making problems: it returns 6700 -> wrong Lc or Le

```
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + "\n\nDone");
        tag.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The function handleResponse just parses the "responseAPDU" from Binary to Hex an highlights the Statusword

Can anybody tell my what is going wrong?
or just help me out?

PS sry for bad english ;)

---

As response to my application-select I get:

```
6f298407a0000000043060a51e50074d41455354524f5f2d046465656e9f38039f5c08bf0c059f4d020b0a9000

6F -> FCI Template 29  
84 -> DF Name 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60  
A5 -> FCI Properietary Template 1E  
50 -> Application Lable 07 4D 41 45 53 54 52 4F 5F 2D 04 64 65 6E  
9F38 -> PDOL 03 9F 5C 08  
BF0C -> FCI Issuer Data 05  
9F4D -> Log Entry 02 0B  
0A Additional Issuer Data
```

But I don't know what ive to insert into the Data fild from the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS.
Iv'e red the guidelines in EMV Book 3, section "5.4 Rules for Using a Data Object List (DOL)".
So do I just have to set the data field 83 03 9F 5C 08
and Lc = 5?

Comment: Please describe your problem better. Your tag says this is java, but the code you show and what you describe as doing is not java. Please describe in more detail what you're doing, and show the relevant code, ideally with a minimal working example (as linked example if it's large, or in-post if it's small).

Comment: Ok ive added the rest of my code i think.  But it is minimal java, the big problems i have with APDU. And here is the tutorial i was working from[link](http://www.nfc.cc/2012/04/02/android-app-reads-paypass-and-paywave-creditcards/)

Comment: this code is not minimal working. Is this arduino-processing? Because that's not java, and you should not be using the java tag for this question.

Comment: No its not "arduino-processing" its done in android an as far as i know android is based on java ;)

Comment: Then I strongly suggest adding all the relevant information to your post. You're working in Android (you have the right tag now), so what are you doing in Android? "GET PROCESSING OPTIONS" is not something you do in the source, for instance, so what are you doing, with what, what do you expect, and what do you see happening instead. Remember: we're just humans reading your question. If you don't provide as much information as possible, we probably can't answer your question without guessing (sometimes we guess right, sometimes we don't, but most people don't want to waste time with guessing)

Comment: ok u asked for everything, here is everything. I thougt it would be to much to copy the whole code.

Comment: it's not, but now you still need to describe what you think you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what you see happening instead. If you get errors, show the actual error (copy paste it as quoted text, for instance), and anything else that is relevant.

Comment: So ive now added some comments and what actally goes wrong.So do u have any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to help you, the entire ADPU dialog (commands/responses) would be needed.

However, based on your code : hardcoding your select_Dir and select_Applet commands is correct, but **you can't hardcode the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command** whose syntax depends on the response of the card (ICC) to your select_Applet command.

[EMV 4.3 Book 1](http://www.emvco.com/download_agreement.aspx?id=652), *"Table 45: SELECT Response Message Data Field (FCI) of an ADF"*, explains that a successful card response to the SELECT command contains a "Processing Options Data Object List" (PDOL, tag 9F38). That's the list of fields required by the card to process the transaction (ex : amount, ...). These fields values are to be returned to the card by the terminal (your phone) through the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command data field (tag 83), as documented in [EMV 4.3 book 3](http://www.emvco.com/download_agreement.aspx?id=654), section *"6.5.8.3 Data Field Sent in the Command Message"* :

> *The data field of the command message is a data object coded **according to the PDOL provided by the ICC**, as defined in section 5.4, and is introduced by the tag '83'. When the data object list is not provided by the ICC, the terminal sets the length field of the template to zero. Otherwise, the length field of the template is the total length of the value fields of the data objects transmitted to the ICC.*

Knowing that :

- Your selected AID (A0 00 00 00 04 30 60) is a Mastercard Maestro one, which is unlikely to have an empty PDOL
- But your GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command does not list any value in its data field
- You probably have a mismatch between the length of your GET PROCESSING OPTIONS data field and the total length of the fields asked by the card in the PDOL, hence the 6700 checking error returned by the card (EMV Book 1, *"Table 33: GET RESPONSE Error Conditions"*).

You have identified the PDOL requested by the card as : 9F38 -> 03 9F 5C 08.
The 03 tells you the PDOL is 3 bytes long. 9F5C is the tag of the requested field, 08 is the length of the field value that is to be returned by the phone.

Tag 9F5C is defined in EMV Contactless 2.3 [Book C2 kernel 2 specification](http://www.emvco.com/download_agreement.aspx?id=820), section *"A.1.59 DS Requested Operator ID"*. The DS Requested Operator ID is defined as

> *Contains the Terminal determined operator identifier for data
>   storage. It is sent to the Card in the GET PROCESSING
>   OPTIONS command.*

I'm not familiar with this tag, so I can't tell you what a proper value is.
However, here is what the data field of the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command should look like, assuming a DS Requested Operator ID has value 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08, and given the Data Object List formatting guidelines in [EMV Book 3](http://www.emvco.com/download_agreement.aspx?id=654), section "5.4 Rules for Using a Data Object List (DOL)" :

> 83 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08

and Lc = 10

Comment: Updated my post to detail the expected GET PROCESSING OPTIONS data field based on M4thoTiX description of the PDOL returned by the card.

Comment: I have found that DS Requested Operator ID can safely be set to all zeros so the full GET PROCESSING OPTIONS could be : 80 A8 00 00 83 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00