# APDU commands to get data from NFC tag using ISODEP

Tags: android, command, nfc, apdu

I am trying to read the information stored on my German Sparkasse Girocard. My app successfully recognizes the (ISODEP) tag. To read the stored information, I need to send a sequence of APDU commands, but I am not sure which.
From my understanding I need to send a SELECT command first:

```
byte[] SELECT = {
                    (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
                    (byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction
                    (byte) 0x04, // P1  Parameter 1
                    (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
                    (byte) 0x09, // Lc
                    (byte) 0xD2,0x76,0x00,0x00,0x25,0x47,0x41,0x01,0x00, // AID
                    (byte) 0x00 //Le
            };
Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
IsoDep tag = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent);
tag.connect();
byte[] result = tag.transceive(SELECT);
text.setText(Integer.toHexString(result[0]) + ", " + Integer.toHexString(result[1]));
```

The status response should be 9000 if it works. I am getting 6F44 which indicates that there was some sort of error (I think). I am also not quite sure if I am using the correct AID, but it has also not worked using others, which I thought could be correct.

What is my error and which commands do I have to send to retrieve the data?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting data from an EMV card (e.g. Girocard, Mastercard, Visacard) is more a "question and answer" puzzle - you are asking the card, get a response, analyze the data and ask the next question.

The analyzing part is done here by using the "TLV Utilities" from emvlab.org (https://emvlab.org/tlvutils/).

To get more information about the Application Identifier ("AID"s) see the complete list at: https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix/.

Here is an example of reading a German Girocard (mine is from a "Volksbank"):

**Step 1: ask the card which applications are on the card using the "select PPSE" command. The 2 bytes at the end "90 00" say that the answer is successfull:**

```
selectPpseCommand: 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
selectPpseResponse: 6F 67 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 55 BF 0C 52 61 19 4F 09 A0 00 00 00 59 45 43 01 00 87 01 01 9F 0A 08 00 01 05 01 00 00 00 00 61 1A 4F 0A A0 00 00 03 59 10 10 02 80 01 87 01 01 9F 0A 08 00 01 05 01 00 00 00 00 61 19 4F 09 D2 76 00 00 25 47 41 01 00 87 01 01 9F 0A 08 00 01 05 01 00 00 00 00 90 00
Parsed response:
6F File Control Information (FCI) Template
    84 Dedicated File (DF) Name
        325041592E5359532E4444463031
    A5 File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
        BF0C File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
            61 Application Template
                4F Application Identifier (AID) – card
                    A00000005945430100
                87 Application Priority Indicator
                    01
                9F0A Unknown tag
                    0001050100000000
            61 Application Template
                4F Application Identifier (AID) – card
                    A0000003591010028001
                87 Application Priority Indicator
                    01
                9F0A Unknown tag
                    0001050100000000
            61 Application Template
                4F Application Identifier (AID) – card
                    D27600002547410100
                87 Application Priority Indicator
                    01
                9F0A Unknown tag
                    0001050100000000
```

There are 3 applications with 3 different AIDs available on the card:

```
A00000005945430100: Zentraler Kreditausschuss (ZKA) Germany Girocard Electronic Cash
A0000003591010028001: Euro Alliance of Payment Schemes s.c.r.l. – EAPS  Belgium Girocard EAPS   ZKA (Germany)
D27600002547410100: ZKA Germany Girocard ATM
```

**Step 2: Now I'm reading the first AID using the "Select AID" command - the AID is 18 characters = 9 bytes long:**

```
selectAidCommand: 00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 00 59 45 43 01 00 00
selectAidResponse: 6F 47 84 09 A0 00 00 00 59 45 43 01 00 A5 3A 50 08 67 69 72 6F 63 61 72 64 87 01 01 9F 38 06 9F 02 06 9F 1D 02 5F 2D 04 64 65 65 6E BF 0C 1A 9F 4D 02 19 0A 9F 6E 07 02 80 00 00 30 30 00 9F 0A 08 00 01 05 01 00 00 00 00 90 00
Parsed response:
6F File Control Information (FCI) Template
    84 Dedicated File (DF) Name
        A00000005945430100
    A5 File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
        50 Application Label
            g i r o c a r d
        87 Application Priority Indicator
            01
        9F38 Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)
            9F02 06
            9F1D 02
        5F2D Language Preference
            d e e n
        BF0C File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
            9F4D Log Entry
                190A
            9F6E Unknown tag
                02800000303000
            9F0A Unknown tag
                0001050100000000
```

**Step 3: get the processing options to read the card details**

This is the first "tricky" point as it is not easy how to explain to get the right data for your card/AID. In the above response there is a section for the Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL) the card is requesting and the length of the fields - here we do have 2 fields with a length of 6 and 2 bytes, in total 8 bytes. The 8 bytes are just 8 "x00"s with the "header" 83 08, so the complete length is 10 bytes = x0A:

```
9F38 Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)
    9F02 06
    9F1D 02
```

A more detailed explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20810855/8166854

```
getProcessingOptionsCommand: 80 A8 00 00 0A 83 08 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
getProcessingOptionsResponse: 77 1E 82 02 19 80 94 18 18 01 01 00 20 01 01 00 20 04 04 00 08 05 05 01 08 07 07 01 08 03 03 01
Parsed response:
77 Response Message Template Format 2
    82 Application Interchange Profile
        1980
    94 Application File Locator (AFL)
        18010100 20010100 20040400 08050501 08070701 08030301
```

The most important part for the next step is the "Application File Locator (AFL)" - we need to read the file system with the data that are coded in these 4 byte blocks.

**Step 4: read the records from the card**

This is the part where I get lost when trying to read the card. You need to get the SFI and RECORD from the first 3 bytes of an AFL block and run a read record command. The following command reads the 4th sector of the AFL list - the command may work or not with your card and if it works you may get different data from your card.

**WARNING**: providing the response data to an internet form may reveal data like account number or
credit card number - my response is masked so the account number is not 1111111111:

```
readRecordCommand:  00 B2 05 0C 00
readRecordResponse: 70 38 5F 24 03 21 12 31 5A 0A 67 26 42 89 11 11 11 11 11 7F 5F 34 01 02 5F 28 02 02 80 9F 07 02 FF C0 9F 0D 05 FC 40 A4 80 00 9F 0E 05 00 10 18 00 00 9F 0F 05 FC 40 A4 98 00 90 00
Parsed response:
70 EMV Proprietary Template
    5F24 Application Expiration Date
        211231
    5A Application Primary Account Number (PAN)
        6726428911111111117F
    5F34 Application Primary Account Number (PAN) Sequence Number
        02
    5F28 Issuer Country Code
        0280
    9F07 Application Usage Control
        FFC0
    9F0D Issuer Action Code – Default
        FC40A48000
    9F0E Issuer Action Code – Denial
        0010180000
    9F0F Issuer Action Code – Online
        FC40A49800
```

I strongly recommend that you use a library for the steps 3 and 4; I'm using

https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment

for this.

This is just a basic explanation for the first steps but now you get some useful responds from your card - good luck for your next steps.

A complete Android example app for the above mentioned library is here (disclaimer: I'm the author):

https://github.com/AndroidCrypto/Android-EMV-NFC-Paycard-Example

Comment: Thank you for your great response! In getProcessingOptionsCommand at step 3 there seems to be a "rouge" 01: getProcessingOptionsCommand: 80 A8 00 00 0A 83 08 00 00 00 00 00 **01** 00 00 00, how do you know where to put that? From the PDOL I got the length 06 and 04, + 2 = 0C.

Comment: For my cards it made no difference if I used the "01" or "00", so change it or not. If your PDOL returns 2 tags with length of 06 + 10 the complete getProcessingOptionsCommand would be: 80 A8 00 00 0C 83 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (so 10 * x00's plus the x00 at the end). For a Visa card this does NOT work for me, my cards needed to get some more "real" data like transaction amount and date. For Mastercards I didn't get a PDOL so you need an "empty" command but that's off-topic of the question.